# Multiple values in crosstab report MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, report, crosstab

I'm working on a database to replace the hundreds of monthly excel spreadsheets keeping track of our employee performance reports. My boss wants to be able to view the data in a weekly summary view. The current excel table doing this looks similar to the following below:

```
        |----Sun #DATE#-----|----Mon #DATE#-----|...    |Sat... |   Totals|
TEAM-1  |S1 |S2 |S3 |S4 |S5 |S1 |S2 |S3 |S4 |S5 |...    |...    |...
Empl-1  |## |## |## |## |## |...
Empl-2  |...
Empl-3  |...
...
TEAM-SUM|## |## |## |## |## |...->|SubTotal|

TEAM-2  |...
...

Daily-SUM|...->|GrandTotal|
```

I have a table that stores the `Sx` values for each recorded day. The fields are `RowID` `EmployeeID` `TeamID` `DateRecorded` `Sx`...

I've tried getting a layout similar to the above in a report, but it's eluding me. I tried a crosstab query, but it only allows one value and one column header, so this doesn't work to recreate ~5 values under each column header. Is there a way to recreate the layout in an access report given the table above, or is there a way to rework the layout to convey the same information?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont necessarily need to create an Access report, you can also create an Access form that has a datagrid subform that can mimic your Excel report layout. Dropdown lookup fields can be placed in the upper header form for dynamically building the queries to populate the datagrid subform with the desired results.

You will also want to create another form for entering and editing the data. This form will also provide better data validation controls that minimize or can totally eliminate data entry errors.

Up front, It will help if you can edit your question to include the tables, fields and relationships you created for storing the data you imported from Excel. Keep in mind that most Excel data is stored in flat un-normalized tables, and you want to take advantage of the relational database architecture that Access offers.

Comment: There really aren't any other tables. There's an Employee table which has EmployeeID and Name, and a team table with team name and ID. The Excel files were just filled with copies of the table described above, one for each week.

I have a form already that allows each team lead to input the data for their team. This is just so the boss can see the summary on a weekly basis. A form should be able to work to show this particular view when required.

Comment: I did talk to my boss about it, and he likes the flexibility of the form I built better than the old format anyway. thanks for your perspective